# AutoMapper self referencing object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, automapper

I have a Conference that has a list of a related Conference. I want the top level conference to give a list of its related conferences but for it to stop there.

I tried the following but when setting maxDepth to 1 I get null for the first child. When setting maxDepth to 2 I get a stockoverflow. If any one knows how to fix this help is appreciated. Thanks, Alex

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Conference, Dto.Conference>().MaxDepth(2);
```

First time using automapper, let me try to explain what I'm trying to solve with MaxDepth:

Conference has a list of associated Conference. So Conference A has an associated Conference B. And Conference B has an associated Conference A.

Now I am sending a list of Conferences with WCF. Clearly sending Conference A over the wire will result in a stack overflow. Is it possible to prevent this with automapper while keeping the first level of associated conferences

Comment: Hmmm you may have found a bug with AutoMapper.  I recreated your issue with NULL for the first child.  However, when I set MaxDepth to 2, it just pushed the NULL child down a level, it didn't Stackoverflow.     I'm using AutoMapper 3.3.1.0       -  Are you auto-mapping POCOs in memory at that point or are you using Project on an IQueryable in EF?

Comment: I edited my question. auto-mapping POCOs in memory.. thanks for the help

Comment: Here's an answer that may suggest a different approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505128/circular-reference-causing-stack-overflow-with-automapper