# Migrating to AutoMapper 5 - Circular references

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-5

I'm having a `System.StackOverflowException` when trying to Map something in AutoMapper 5 that worked previously with AutoMapper 4.

After googling a bit around I found out that it caused by [Circular references](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide#circular-references).

The AutoMapper Documentation says:

> Previously, AutoMapper could handle circular references by keeping
>   track of what was mapped, and on every mapping, check a local
>   hashtable of source/destination objects to see if the item was already
>   mapped. It turns out this tracking is very expensive, and you need to
>   opt-in using PreserveReferences for circular maps to work.
>   Alternatively, you can configure MaxDepth:
>
> ```
> // Self-referential mapping
> cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>().MaxDepth(3);
>
> // Circular references between users and groups
> cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>().PreserveReferences();
> ```

So I added `.MaxDepth(3)` to my code and it works now again.

However I do not undertand what the real problem is and what I did by adding the line :)

My Questions:

- What means 'circular references' in regards of Category/CategoryDto ?
- What exactly does `.MaxDepth()`?  Why 3 is used in the sample?
- What is `.PreserveReferences()` for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`PreserveReferences` will make the map behave like `AutoMapper4` as you are used to. It will make `AutoMapper` keep track of what is mapped and prevent it from causing an overflow.

The other option is to set a depth that you wish `AutoMapper` to traverse. With a set depth it will map a self referencing model the number of times specified.

Circular references would be a class such as:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public Category Child {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}
```

A class referencing itself, property `Child` means you can nest this object many times.

Comment: I set Depth as 1. Still stack overflows...! It feels like noway the configuration is listening to us...