# automapper error mapping types of collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, mapping, automapper

Here are my viewmodels and datamodels

```
public class League{
    ICollection<Player> Players{get;set;}
}

public class Player{
    string name{get;set;}
}

public class LeagueViewModel{
    ICollection<PlayerViewModel> Players{get;set;}
}

public class PlayerViewModel{
    string name{get;set;}
}
```

And here are my mapping profiles

```
public class LeagueProfile : Profile
{
    public LeagueProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<League, LeagueModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Players, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Players));

        CreateMap<LeagueModel, League>()
            .ForMember(m => m.Players, opt => opt.MapFrom(c => c.Players));
    }
}

 public class PlayerProfile : Profile
    {
        public PlayerProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<PlayerModel, Player>().ForMember(c => c.Parent, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Parent));
            CreateMap<Player, PlayerModel>().ForMember(c => c.Parent, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Parent));

            CreateMap<ICollection<Player>, ObservableCollection<PlayerModel>>();
            CreateMap<ObservableCollection<PlayerModel>, ICollection<Player>>();

        }

    }
```

but when I call

```
league.Players = mapper.Map(model.Players,league.Players);
```

I get

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
LeagueModel -> League
UI.Infrastructure.Models.LeagueModel -> DataLayer.Entities.League

Type Map configuration:
LeagueModel -> League
UI.Infrastructure.Models.LeagueModel -> DataLayer.Entities.League

Property:
Players
  Source=Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
  StackTrace:
       at lambda_method(Closure , LeagueModel , League , ResolutionContext )
       at UI.Infrastructure.Services.GenerateRoundService.ConstructRounds() in D:\TFS\TournamentSoftware\UI.Infrastructure\Services\GenerateRoundService.cs:line 29
       at UI.Infrastructure.Models.LeagueModel.ConstructRounds() in D:\TFS\TournamentSoftware\UI.Infrastructure\Models\LeagueModel.cs:line 108
       at UI.Infrastructure.Models.LeagueModel.GenerateRounds() in D:\TFS\TournamentSoftware\UI.Infrastructure\Models\LeagueModel.cs:line 86
       at UI.LeagueModule.ViewModels.LeagueViewModel.GenerateRounds() in D:\TFS\TournamentSoftware\UI.LeaugeModule\ViewModels\LeagueViewModel.cs:line 91
       at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object o)
       at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object arg)
       at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommandBase.<Execute>d__15.MoveNext()
  InnerException: 
       HResult=-2146233054
       Message=Method 'Add' in type 'Proxy<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[DataLayer.Entities.Player_DataLayer_Version=1.0.0.0_Culture=neutral_PublicKeyToken=null]]_mscorlib_Version=4.0.0.0_Culture=neutral_PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089>' from assembly 'AutoMapper.Proxies, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' does not have an implementation.
       Source=mscorlib
       TypeName=Proxy<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[DataLayer.Entities.Player_DataLayer_Version=1.0.0.0_Culture=neutral_PublicKeyToken=null]]_mscorlib_Version=4.0.0.0_Culture=neutral_PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089>
       StackTrace:
            at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.TermCreateClass(RuntimeModule module, Int32 tk, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
            at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateTypeNoLock()
            at System.Reflection.Emit.TypeBuilder.CreateType()
            at AutoMapper.Execution.ProxyGenerator.EmitProxy(Type interfaceType)
            at AutoMapper.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1()
            at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
            at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
            at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
            at AutoMapper.Execution.ProxyGenerator.GetProxyType(Type interfaceType)
            at lambda_method(Closure , LeagueModel , League , ResolutionContext )
       InnerException:
```

Can anyone help me shed some light on this? I've looked for a similar issue elsewhere and have implemented the solutions but noting is working.

Comment: You don't need to create explicit mappings for collections/lists. Remove these lines from `PlayerProfile` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks @Rabban, I tried but I now get a stack overflow error at the same place. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Do the `Player` points to the `League`? Maybe there is a circle reference.

Comment: Yeah they do, thats the Parent mapping on the PlayerProfile.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40650571/6666799), it should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Rabban that has fixed my problem!

Comment: @Rabban would you be able to shed any light on a previous question I asked? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136015/using-automapper-to-map-objects-within-constructor
I think im going to have to take the parent object out of the constructor to make it work, but im not sure how to resolve the IMapper requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rabban said in the comments removing the explicit collection conversion and then adding

```
PreserveReferences()
```

to my profile solved the problem./