# Stack Overflow when AutoMapper project a circular reference object

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, automapper, stack-overflow

I have the folowing class and its dto:

```
public class Node
{
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Node> ChildrenNode { get; set; }

    public virtual Node ParentNode { get; set; }
}

public class NodeDto
{
    public int NodeId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NodeDto> ChildrenNode { get; set; }

    public NodeDto ParentNode { get; set; }
}
```

And my mapper is just simple:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Node, NodeDto>();
```

When I call ProjectTo from an IQueryable, I get a StackOverflowException. I already tried  `Mapper.CreateMap<Node, NodeDto>().MaxDepth(3)` and `Mapper.CreateMap<Node, NodeDto>().PreserveReferences()` and none of these worked.

What can I do to mantain self reference?

If it'll be of any help, I need to access ParentNode and ChildrenNode from any depht, but inside a ParentNode I don't need a ChildrenNode. Something like this: `node.ParentNode` and `node.ChildrenNode[0].ChildrenNode`, but no need for `node.ParentNode.ChildrenNode`;

Comment: One technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505128/circular-reference-causing-stack-overflow-with-automapper

Comment: I'll try to adapt to this approach tomorrow. WIsh me luck!