# Automapper Circular Reference

Tags: c#, .net, automapper-5

I have two objects

```
class Order{ public List<Case> Cases {get;set;} }
class Case { public Order Order {get;set;}
```

I map them using Automapper 5.2.0

```
CreateMap<CustomerOrder, Order>().PreserveReferences()
.ForMember(d=>d.Case, o=>o.MapFrom(s=>s.Case));

CreateMap<OrderCase, Case>().PreserveReferences()
.ForMember(d=>d.Order, o=>MapFrom(s=>s.Order))
```

Got a circular reference and stack overflow.

UPDATE
Not exactly [Circular reference causing stack overflow with Automapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505128/circular-reference-causing-stack-overflow-with-automapper)

When I map an Order, I need to receive an Order with multiple Cases

- Order
- - Case (.Order must be null or reference to parent order)
- - Case (the same)

Also when I map Case I need the corresponding Order to be filled.

- Case
- - Order (no cases)

Comment: I think you need to have one of the 2 ignored by automapper and handle it yourself. Or check this one out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505128/circular-reference-causing-stack-overflow-with-automapper

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular reference causing stack overflow with Automapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11505128/circular-reference-causing-stack-overflow-with-automapper)

Comment: I tried solution from post you referring to, but unfortunately it is not exactly I need. I will update my post to clarify in  minute

Comment: Still sounds like the solution in the previous one?

Comment: When I map case the order is null

Comment: can you show an example of something that's not mapping the way you want?