# How to ignore property of property in AutoMapper mapping?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, stack-overflow, nullreferenceexception

Image a `Person` and a `Group` class with a many-to-many relationship. A person has a list of groups and a group has a list of people.

When mapping `Person` to `PersonDTO` I have a `stack overflow exception` because AutoMapper can't handle the `Person`>`Groups`>`Members`>`Groups`>`Members`>...

So here's the example code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Members { get; set; }
}

public class PersonDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<GroupDTO> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class GroupDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PersonDTO> Members { get; set; }
}
```

When I use .ForMember in creating a mapper, the first mapper that gets executed throws a `null reference exception`.

Here's the code for the mapper:

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Groups.Select(y => y.Members), opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Group, GroupDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Members.Select(y => y.Groups), opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();
```

So what am I missing or doing wrong? When I remove the .ForMember methods, the `null reference exception` is not thrown anymore.

**UPDATE**: I really want to emphasize the **main point** of my question is **how to ignore a property of a property**. This code is just a rather simple example.

**UPDATE 2: This is how I fixed it, big thanks to [Lucian-Bargaoanu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811700/lucian-bargaoanu)**

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Groups.Select(y => y.Members), opt => opt.Ignore())
    .PreserveReferences() // This is the solution!
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<Group, GroupDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Members.Select(y => y.Groups), opt => opt.Ignore())
    .PreserveReferences() // This is the solution!
    .ReverseMap();
```

Thanks to `.PreserveReferences()` the circular references get fixed!

Comment: Thank you @Esperadoce, but my code is a bit less simple than the example. I really want to ignore a **property of a property** in AutoMapper.

Comment: yes you're right, i remove my flag !

Comment: Yes @KirillShlenskiy, they are indeed fields, I just wanted to keep it very simple. I'll update my question.

Comment: Why don't you just use `.ForMember(x => x.members, o => o.Ignore())` ?

Comment: @kayess, it's not `x.Members` I want to ignore, it's the `Groups` property of the `x.members`, to withstand stack overflow exception.

Comment: your problem is loop reference 
So check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11505745/2954082

Comment: @kayess no the `members.Groups` has a property referring back to `members`, that's what's creating the stack overflow

Comment: @Esperadoce Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: @Esperadoce Doesn't work for my code... Because I work with `IList` properties

Comment: Sorry @kayess I forgot to update that part of the code. I updated it because someone was addressing properties != fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should just work. See https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide#circular-references. There is also a PR pending https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/2233.

Comment: Yes! Oh my gawd that fixed it! Thank you so much! I hoped I would not have to use a lot of ugly code, but wow just adding `.PreserveReferences()` fixed it! Thank you again.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. **Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.** Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you are experiencing comes from wrong assumption that Groups in PersonDTO.Groups are the same as GroupDTO - it cannot be so without the infinite dependency loop. The following code should work for you:

```
CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Groups, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
    {
        dest.Groups = src.Groups.Select(g => new GroupDTO { Name = g.Name }).ToList()
    });

CreateMap<Group, GroupDTO>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Members, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap()
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
    {
        dest.Members = src.Members.Select(p => new PersonDTO { Name = p.Name }).ToList()
    });
```

You basically need to teach AutoMapper that in case of PersonDTO.Groups property it should map GroupDTO objects differently.

But I think that your problem is more like architectural issue than code one. PersonDTO.Groups should not be of type GroupDTO - you are here only interested in groups particular user belongs to and not other members of his groups. You should have some simpler type like:

```
public class PersonGroupDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

(the name is up to you of course) to only identify the group without passing additionally members.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was I way I tried it, but it just didn't look so clean having to make a seperate DTO just to fix that issue. I updated my question with a very simple solution to fix circular references with automapper.

Comment: Only take into account that using PreserveReferences slows down automapper to some degree :) Except of that you are fine.